# how to upload file to Google cloud Storage via Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, delphi-2010, delphi-xe

hello my friends i am need upload a files to google cloud storage account using Delphi , have one have a example for me. Thank

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Here, we expect questions to be related to specific issues which you experience during development, and expect that you already have a clear understanding of what you're trying to accomplish. Questions asking for a broad scope of how to accomplish something are not acceptable here. Please do your best to do your own research and feel free to ask questions when you get stuck somewhere that you can't find a solution to.

Answer (score 3):

There is a component: TAdvGDrive that can do this for you.
http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/cloudpack.asp

Comment: He was asking for Google Cloud Storage, not for Google Drive.

Comment: @FjodrSo, the cloudpack supports Google Cloud Storage as well.